# Compare two columns, if a match replace one with another cell beside

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add category codes to text categories in an excel spreadsheet. I have a column A with all the category names in text, including duplicates. I have column B with all the category names in text, not including duplicates and I have column C which has the category codes not including duplicates. Each code in column C alligns with its category in column B
For example:

> A:
> Domestic Ware
>
> B:
> Agri Tools
>
> C:
> 051

051 is the code for agri tools. I want to take the string in column A, Search for this string in column B and then replace the string that was in column A with the code in C.

Is there anyway to do this using VBA or excels built in functions?

Comment: This can be done using the VLOOKUP function

Comment: Tried using VLOOKUP for it, not working out for me. Any chance you could give me an example of the function?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column A contains a list of Category names including duplicates, and columns B & C contain (the same) category names and Category ID's without duplicates (i.e. a "category code table"), you can

- in column D (or maybe better insert a new column between A and B)
- for each entry in A you enter `=VLOOKUP(Ax,$B$y:$C$z,2,FALSE)`

whereby

x = current row number

y = starting row of "category code table"

z = end row of "category code table"

You make the coord's of the lookup table absolute to prevent y & z being changed as you copy the formula down.

Comment: Thanks! Worked, but I had to put an ISERROR before it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to **replace** values in column **A**, give this small macro a try:

```
Sub FixColumnA()
    Dim nA As Long, nB As Long, v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    nA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    nB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To nA
        With Cells(i, "A")
            v = .Value
            For j = 1 To nB
                If v = Cells(j, "B").Value Then
                    .Value = Cells(j, "C").Value
                End If
            Next j
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, the other one worked so didn't test this but thank you

Comment: @SmalliSax  Glad to help !